# Windows Azure REST API to get Containers List: Signature Authentication error

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to list the containers in my windows azure storage account. but  i'm struck with an exception 
"The remote server returned an error: (403) Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.."

But i have included the signature as per the instructions given, do any one find any mistake in my code ?

```
private static String SignThis(string StringToSign,string  Key,string  Account)
        {

            String signature = string.Empty;
            byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
            {
                Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToSign);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }

            String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0} {1}:{2}",
                "SharedKey",
                Account,
                signature);
            return authorizationHeader;
        }
        static void ListContainers()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            string Key = @"MyStorageAccountKey";
            string Account = @"MyStorageAccountName";

            DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;

            string dataStr = dt.ToString ("R",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string StringToSign = String.Format("GET\n"
                + "\n" // content encoding
                + "\n" // content language
                + "\n" // content length
                + "\n" // content md5
                + "\n" // content type
                + "\n" // date
                + "\n" // if modified since
                + "\n" // if match
                + "\n" // if none match
                + "\n" // if unmodified since
                + "\n" // range
                + "x-ms-date:" + dataStr + "\nx-ms-version:2014-02-14\n" // headers
                + "/{0}\ncomp:list", Account);

            string auth = SignThis(StringToSign, Key, Account);
            string method = "GET";
            string urlPath = string.Format ("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list", Account);
            Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);
            HttpWebRequest reque = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            reque.Method = method;
            reque.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
            reque.Headers.Add("x-ms-date",dataStr);
            reque.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2014-02-14");

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) reque.GetResponse ()) {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please do not store your Azure Storage account keys on your iOS app, otherwise your customers can get it. You should sign the signatures on your service.

Comment: Sure i will not, it is just an sample. thanks.